# iPhoneHTTPServer/CocoaHTTPServer File Uploads

Tags: javascript, iphone, file, upload, cocoahttpserver

I have managed to get the iPhoneHTTPServer sample within CocoaHTTPServer to work - I can display web pages, run JavaScript etc but what I cannot figure out is how to upload a file from my PC onto my iPhone.

I have looked at various JavaScript examples for "uploading files" but they appear only load files on the client side and don't actually upload files onto the server - ie - my iPhone.

Can somebody please provide me some example code that does this or some guidance as to how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

OK! I found the SimpleFileUploadServer sample in the CocoaHTTPServer "Samples" folder.. I've been able to cut, paste and learn from that. All sorted.